# C# - Need to call child override function whilst only 'knowing' the parent

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I have these classes in a game (simplified):

```
public class GameUnit
{
    public enum UnitType
    {
        FighterUnit,
        MageUnit,
        Count,
    }

    public UnitType type;

    public virtual void OnUnitSelected()
    {
        HighlightUnit();
    }
}

public class FighterUnit : GameUnit
{
    public FighterUnit()
    {
        type = UnitType.FighterUnit;
    }

    public override void OnUnitSelected()
    {
        PlayFighterSound();
        base.OnUnitSelected();
    }

    public void Punch()
    {
        PunchInfrontOfMe();
    }
}

public class MageUnit : GameUnit
{
    public MageUnit()
    {
        type = UnitType.MageUnit;
    }

    public override void OnUnitSelected()
    {
        PlayMageSound();
        base.OnUnitSelected();
    }

    public void CastSpell()
    {
        CreateSpellAtPosition();
    }
}
```

I store these units in a list, and can spawn them and click on them like so:

```
public class GameUnitController
{
    public List<GameUnit> units;
    public void SpawnUnit(GameUnit.UnitType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case GameUnit.UnitType.FighterUnit:
                FighterUnit newFighterUnit = new FighterUnit();
                units.Add(newFighterUnit);
                break;

            case GameUnit.UnitType.MageUnit:
                MageUnit newMageUnit = new MageUnit();
                units.Add(newMageUnit);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void UnitClicked(GameUnit unit)
    {
        unit.OnUnitSelected();
    }
}
```

When I need to, I can cast them to their child class when needed for specific logic, like so:

```
public void PerformAction(GameUnit unit)
    {
        switch (unit.type)
        {
            case GameUnit.UnitType.FighterUnit:
                ((FighterUnit)unit).Punch();
                break;

            case GameUnit.UnitType.MageUnit:
                ((MageUnit)unit).CastSpell();
                break;
        }
    }
```

However, my code base is already starting to get to the point where I'm adding lots of switch statements for class types, and I'd like a simpler way of handling the more generic function calls (see OnUnitSelected issue).

The current issue with OnUnitSelected, is that how it is written here, it only calls the parent class's OnUnitSelected, when I want it to go through all of them.

Is there a good way that I can utilise my enum to create something generic in the base class that could return it as it's correct class and not have to go through lots of switch statements, which will become bigger and bigger as more units are added.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: Solution that I went for in the end:

Edited GameUnit as such:

```
public class GameUnit
{
    public enum UnitType
    {
        FighterUnit,
        MageUnit,
        Count,
    }

    public UnitType type;

    public virtual void OnUnitSelected()
    {
        HighlightUnit();
    }

    public virtual void RunMethod(Action method)
    {
        method();
    }

    public void DoAsChild(Action method)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case UnitType.FighterUnit:
                FighterUnit fighterUnit = (FighterUnit)this;
                fighterUnit.RunMethod(method);
                break;

            case UnitType.MageUnit:
                MageUnit mageUnit = (MageUnit)this;
                mageUnit.RunMethod(method);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And edited the derived classes to override the method:

```
public class FighterUnit : GameUnit
{
    public FighterUnit()
    {
        type = UnitType.FighterUnit;
    }

    public override void OnUnitSelected()
    {
        PlayFighterSound();
        base.OnUnitSelected();
    }

    public void Punch()
    {
        PunchInfrontOfMe();
    }

    public override void RunMethod(Action method)
    {
        method();
    }
}

public class MageUnit : GameUnit
{
    public MageUnit()
    {
        type = UnitType.MageUnit;
    }

    public override void OnUnitSelected()
    {
        PlayMageSound();
        base.OnUnitSelected();
    }

    public void CastSpell()
    {
        CreateSpellAtPosition();
    }

    public override void RunMethod(Action method)
    {
        method();
    }
}
```

So now when I have an overriden function like OnUnitSelected, I can call on the parent which will in turn cast itself to the correct child, and call the method from the child class:

```
public void UnitClicked(GameUnit unit)
{
    unit.DoAsChild(unit.OnUnitSelected);
}
```

Comment: If your unit classes only have one Action, you could add a virtual Action method in the Unit Base class and override them. Then you can just call Action from the base class like you did with OnUnitSelected.

Comment: I have done this before, but it's been awhile.  I think that I used generics with the "new" attribute specified.  IIRC, the problem with Actions, et. al., is that you cannot override Class static methods, only non-static (object) methods, so you have to first have an instance of an object type before you can create a new instance of that object type.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had a look into using Actions and think I've come up with a decent solution, it works for me anyway, have edited the question to show the solution.